# Мини двиг на VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, visual-basic

Скажите, я хочу сделать мини конструктор игр, вот что он сможет сделать: есть файл config.ini в нём прописаны пути к картинкам. Вот пример такого файла

```
[Player]
Player = D:\test\player.bmp
[Chat]
ChatBox = D:\test\chatbox.bmp
```

Программа считывала эти картинки и помещала их в ImageBox (а у него свойство `AutoSize = True`)... вот такая задачка, не могу решить. Искал, но не нашёл.

Answer (score 1):

До конца не понял вопрос. Если нужно на основе ini файла грузить картинки, то чтение ini-файла делается вызовом функции Windows API

```
Private Declare Auto Function GetPrivateProfileString Lib "kernel32" (ByVal AppName As String, _
    ByVal KeyName As String, _
    ByVal Default As String, _
    ByVal ReturnedString As StringBuilder, _
    ByVal Size As Integer, _
    ByVal FileName As String) As Integer
```

и

```
Dim result As Integer
Dim buffer As StringBuilder

buffer = New StringBuilder(1000)
result = GetPrivateProfileString("AppName", "KeyName", "", buffer, buffer.Capacity, pathToIni)
```

а создание картинки из файла

```
Dim imageX As Image = Image.FromFile(pathToImage)
```